How to round the edges of a whole section/div
I have an image like this
(https://i.sstatic.net/oz4mb8A4.png)
and it zooms in when you hover.
However I am trying to round the edges of the image and the overlay that covers the image when I hover. How do I do this?
This is my code in html
<section class="effects">
<div class="container">

   <div class="image-01-outer">

    <div class="image-01">
      <img src="PHILIPPA'S NEW VIDEO.png" alt="">

          <div class="overlay1">
              <div class="text-content">
                  <h3 class="h3-img"> Header</h3>
                  <p>Body of text. Body.</p>
              </div>
          </div>
  </div>

   </div>

</div>

</section>

and in css I have this
.effects .image-01 
{
border: 1px solid blue;  
border-radius: 4rem;  
position: relative; 
}

.effects .image-01 img
{
    max-width: 120rem;
}

.effects .image-01 .overlay1
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
    background-color: rgba(228, 20, 255, 0.327);
}

.effects .image-01:hover .overlay1
{
    opacity: 1;
}

.effects .image-01:hover 
{
    transition: transform .4s;
    transform: scale(1.1);
    transform-origin: 100% 50%;
}


In your CSS file, set the .effects .image-01 selector to have the rule overflow: hidden

Does this answer your question? Forcing child to obey parent's curved borders in CSS

You should use the overflow property for this. Add it to the parent element as overflow: hidden and it will make it so anything outside of the parent is hidden, thus preventing anything from going past the rounded borders, and making everything rounded! You also should make the parent have it's width set to width: min-content. I suggest centering the text too, and I threw that in there with display: flex, align-items: center, and justify-content: center on the .overlay-1 element, but that's your choice!
(Note: I also changed the max-width of the img so it fits in the preview, that's just for the demo, and isn't integral to my answer.)


.effects .image-01 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-radius: 4rem;
  position: relative;

  width: min-content;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.effects .image-01 img {
  /* max-width: 120rem; */

  max-width: 30rem;
}

.effects .image-01 .overlay1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  background-color: rgba(228, 20, 255, 0.327);

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.effects .image-01:hover .overlay1 {
  opacity: 1;
}

.effects .image-01:hover {
  transition: transform .4s;
  transform: scale(1.1);
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
}
<section class="effects">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="image-01-outer">

      <div class="image-01">
        <img src="https://developers.elementor.com/docs/assets/img/elementor-placeholder-image.png" alt="">

        <div class="overlay1">
          <div class="text-content">
            <h3 class="h3-img"> Header</h3>
            <p>Body of text. Body.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</section>



